# Validating an active record's model value that depends on other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :weight
  after_create :create_category_weight

  def create_category_weight
    self.weight = Weight.new :value => 1/Category.count
  end

end
```

and..

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :value
end
```

I want to reliably set value to be (1/number of categories).  I'd like this to work in the case of category.build_weight, category.new, category.create etc.  I've tried the above approach, as well as using an observer, but its brittle.  Suggestions on different architectural approaches also appreciated.

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extract the creation logic out of the ActiveRecord model and into another class. Something like:

```
class CategoryRepository

  def new_category
    @category = Category.new
    @category.weight = Weight.new(:value => (1 / Category.count))
    @category
  end

  def create_category(attributes)
    @category = Category.create(attributes)
    @category.weight = Weight.new(:value => (1 / Category.count))
    @category.save
    @category
  end

end

@repository = CategoryRepository.new

@category = @repository.new_category

@category = @repository.create_category(params[:category])
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a before validation callback to set the weight, and validate the weight in the model? (If you do that, make sure you take race conditions into consideration...)

Comment: The race condition is the whole problem, unfortunately. ;)

Comment: The safest way to guard against race conditions is probably specifying a database trigger (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger), which will depend on your specific database. Otherwise, you might want to set the weight in an after_initialize callback (although this will still be prone to race conditions).